# Unable to get CAP_CHOWN and CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE working for regular user

Tags: python-2.7, systemd, linux-capabilities

**My requirement**

My python server runs as a regular user on RHEL
But it needs to create files/directories at places it doesn't have access to.
Also needs to do chown those files with random UID/GID

**My approach**

Trying this in capability-only environment, no setuid.
I am trying to make use of cap_chown and cap_dac_override capabilities.
But am totally lost of how to get it working in systemctl kind of environment

At present I have following in the service file:

```
#cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/my_server.service 

[Service]
Type=simple
SecureBits=keep-caps
User=testuser
CapabilityBoundingSet=~
Capabilities=cap_dac_override,cap_chown=eip
ExecStart=/usr/bin/linux_capability_test.py
```

And following on the binary itself:

```
# getcap /usr/bin/linux_capability_test.py
/usr/bin/linux_capability_test.py = cap_chown,cap_dac_override+ei
```

But this here says, that it will never work on scripts:
[Is there a way for non-root processes to bind to "privileged" ports on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413807/is-there-a-way-for-non-root-processes-to-bind-to-privileged-ports-1024-on-l#414258)

With the current setting, the capabilities I have for the running process are:

```
# ps -ef | grep lin
testuser    28268     1  0 22:31 ?        00:00:00 python /usr/bin/linux_capability_test.py

# getpcaps 28268
Capabilities for `28268': = cap_chown,cap_dac_override+i
```

But if I try to create file in /etc/ from within that script:

```
try:
    file_name = '/etc/junk'
    with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
        os.utime(file_name,None)
```

It fails with 'Permission denied'

Is that the same case for me that it won't work ?
Can I use python-prctl module here to get it working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon our discussion above, I did the following:

```
[Service]
Type=simple
User=testuser
SecureBits=keep-caps
Capabilities=cap_chown,cap_dac_override=i
ExecStart=/usr/bin/linux_capability_test.py
```

This starts the server with both those capabilities as inheritable.

Wrote a small C, test code to chown file

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
  {
    int ret = 0;

    ret = chown("/etc/junk", 160, 160);

    return ret;
  }
```

Set following on the gcc'ed binary

```
chown testuser:testuser /usr/bin/chown_c
chmod 550 /usr/bin/chown_c
setcap cap_chown,cap_dac_override=ie /usr/bin/chown_c
```

The server does following to call the binary

```
import prctl
prctl.cap_inheritable.chown = True
prctl.cap_inheritable.dac_override = True
execve('/usr/bin/chown_c',[],os.environ)
```

And I was able to get the desired result

```
# ll /etc/junk 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Aug  8 22:33 /etc/junk

# python capability_client.py 

# ll /etc/junk 
-rw-r--r-- 1 testuser testuser 0 Aug  8 22:33 /etc/junk
```

Answer (score 0):

setuid will not work with scripts because it is a security hole, due to the way that scripts execute.  There are several documents on this.  You can even start by looking at the wikipedia page.

A really good workaround is to write a small C program that will launch your Python script with hard-coded paths to python and the script.  A really good discussion of all the issues may be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166817/using-the-setuid-bit-properly)

Comment: Thanks for your reply and the link. But I think I specifically want to avoid setuid on scripts that is why want to make use of 'Linux capabilities' alone. Which is what my question is about

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** A method to do this, not sure if the best one. Using 'python-prctl' module:

```
1. Ditch 'User=testuser' from my-server.service
2. Start server as root
3. Set 'keep_caps' flag True
4. Do 'setgroups, setgid and setuid'
5. And immediately limit the permitted capability set to 'DAC_OVERRIDE' and 'CHOWN' capability only
6. Set the effective capability for both to True
```

Here is the code for the same

```
import prctl

prctl.securebits.keep_caps = True

os.setgroups([160])
os.setgid(160)
os.setuid(160)

prctl.cap_permitted.limit(prctl.CAP_CHOWN, prctl.CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE)
prctl.cap_effective.dac_override = True
prctl.cap_effective.chown = True`
```

**DONE !!**

Comment: So are you running your entire server with CAP_CHOWN now?

Comment: Yes, that is a caveat here. But I think my original attempt to set Capabilities in the .service file etc was also trying to do the same, set capabilities on entire server. You mentioned in your comment **write a small C program that will launch your Python script with hard-coded paths to python and the script.** I didn't understand that part. In the link which you mentioned, which section should I look for an example ?

Comment: There is a section that starts "The answer to this is to use a setuid binary to execute the script."  But if you hand a random script chown capability, all it has to do is modify and edit a couple of files in /etc, and then it can execute whatever it wants as part of a cron job.  You want a new user for your chown, and you want it very isolated.  See, for example [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31272030/linux-changing-file-ownership-without-a-copy/31748737#31748737).

Comment: Ok, that section. So in my case the binary, with setuid 0, if starts the python server and the server is anyways again doing a setuid(regular_user), it will again loose the capability, right ?   I totally understand the security concern and have raised the same with our folks ;)  The second link which you posted is exactly what I had in mind as alternate approach. In my case the server(also REST server) may need to overwrite/modify/delete files owned by any user and also chown them to any other. How do I give capability to an individual user ?

Comment: Depending on which version of linux you have, you [may not be able to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956732/is-it-possible-to-configure-linux-capabilities-per-user) give capability to users directly.  But you can certainly add the capabilities you want to the permitted and inheritable capabilities of the small C program.  If you can do everything you need in the small C program, you may not need SETUID.  If you need to invoke a script from the program, you should certainly isolate the script by putting it and the C program under control of the separate user.

Comment: **you can certainly add the capabilities you want to the permitted and inheritable capabilities of the small C program. If you can do everything you need in the small C program, you may not need SETUID**  The C program will basically do copy/move/delete and chown operations only. To achieve this, how should I specify the capabilities ? On the program itself, within the program, before calling the program from server ?  Sorry, if I am asking for too much info

Comment: Use the setcap program on the executable.